# Items in another layout do not respond to user events

Tags: java, android, eclipse, events, onclicklistener

Please have a look at the following code

**game_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Game" >

    //Please note the GUI Has been removed


        <include layout="@layout/common_status_bar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Game.java**

```
package game.games;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Game extends Activity {


    private ImageView goToLanguageSelection;
    private ImageView goToInternet;
    private Button giveUp;


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private View commonView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        commonView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.common_status_bar, null);

        //Intializing instance variables
        goToLanguageSelection = (ImageView)commonView.findViewById(R.id.backToLanguageSelectionButton);
        goToInternet = (ImageView)commonView.findViewById(R.id.internetButton);
        giveUp = (Button)commonView.findViewById(R.id.giveUpButton);

        flag = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("LANGUAGE", true);

        //Add listeners

        goToLanguageSelection.setOnClickListener(goToLanguageSelectionClicked);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
        return true;
    }








    //Will get activated when the ThunderBolt image is clicked  
    private OnClickListener goToLanguageSelectionClicked = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),LanguageSelector.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    };


}
```

**common_status_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#373734"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backToLanguageSelectionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thunderbolt" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/internetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/globe_small_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/justForFun"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/giveUpButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here, the **common_status_bar.xml** is a common layout. I have added this layout to `game_activity.xml` by `<include layout="@layout/common_status_bar"/>`.

It displays everything fine, no issue. But the case is I can't make any of it's elements to work. I have attached a `OnClickListener` to the first element of it, the `goToLanguageSelection` but it is not responding to the Click. I tested this by adding the click event to all other buttons, images as well (one at a time) and I got the same result. It is not responding to user click, or whatever.

Why this button and images in separate layout do not respond to the user events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `commonView` should not be created again.

If you want keep a reference of the `common_status_bar.xml`, you can give name it by an id, like the code below:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/common_status_bar"
            layout="@layout/common_status_bar" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then, change this code:

```
       commonView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.common_status_bar, null);
```

to:

```
       commonView = findViewById(R.id.common_status_bar);
```

Comment: how is the issue going?